# How to convert int to double using jquery or javascript when user enter input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert `int` to double using `jquery` or `javascript` when user enter input value?

Here when user enter the input it automatically convert into double values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="TextBox1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var decimalNumber = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
                var integerNumber = parseFloat(decimalNumber);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: You have missing `})` and I am guessing it's a mistake while posting?

Comment: What are you really asking? parseFloat will convert it to a double value. parseInt will convert it to an integer. DecimalNumber in your code is a string, and integerNumber is a double

Answer (score 2):

You have not closed the dom ready function. `});`

There is another problem as well, at the document.ready function, the value of the input will be blank. Which causes error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        var decimalNumber = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
        var integerNumber = parseFloat(decimalNumber);
        alert(integerNumber);
    });
});
```

Here I have binded a change event to the text box.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o1mjxfm6/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear of what you need ,but this should help.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").change(function () {
            var d= document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
            d=parseFloat(d);
            var i = d.toFixed(2);
            alert(i);
        });
    });
```

Also close the `document ready` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I want another source for text box only allows double,not any other integers or characters